# using eval for calling filed in same name that join

Tags: asp.net

I have stored procedure that joining 5 table .i want to call field of name that exist in news table but same field with this name are exist in my store procedure how can i eval("tablename.fieldname") for this problem?

Comment: can you share the structure of the dataset you are receiving or can you post an example.

Comment: Normally when you join tables the columns with same names are postfixed with a number.
Eg:  elementId,elementid1,elementid2